# IIS response status 302 then 200 for same URL

Tags: iis-7.5

What causes IIS 7.5 to send response 302 and then immediately response 200 for the same page URL request. [IE11 F12 Developer Tool Debugger 302 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fvl1.png).

Condition began when IIS web server was upgraded from IIS6 to IIS7.5.  Server log shows the 2 statuses occurring at the same date time second.  Server error occurs for all page request types (HTML, ASP, etc.).

Comment: 302 is a redirect. you may have other application doing the redirect for you

Comment: For simple HTML page, IIS7.5 is sending two status 200 responses.

Comment: For simple HTML page, IIS7.5 is just sending two status 200 responses.

Web site supports Classic ASP and ColdFusion application pages.  For these application page requests, IIS replies first with 302 and then 200 responses. 

Could this have something to do with IIS' ISAPI filtering?